# How do I enforce Set-StrictMode 2 while using global variables

Tags: powershell

If I want to use a Powershell *global variable* together with `class` and `Set-StrictMode -version 2`, how do I do it?

```
Set-StrictMode -version 2
class MyClass{
    [string] MyMethod(){
        $x = $ErrorActionPreference
         ...
```

Powershell complains

```
$x = $ErrorActionPreference
Variable is not assigned in the method.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of assignment is considered harmful in StrictMode 2. `$ErrorActionPreference` is not declared in class/function scope. It's available in [global scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

Your example, valid in Strict Mode 2, should look like:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2

class MyClass {
    [string] MyMethod(){
        $x = $global:ErrorActionPreference
        return $x
    }
}

[MyClass]::new().MyMethod()
```

Comment: FYI, `$ErrorActionPreference` is not a string type, but actually `System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference`.